# Convert images from base64 to PNG intermittent error

Tags: coldfusion

I have an application that produces an image using HTML5 canvas. When the user wants to save the results, it flattens all the canvas layers into a new canvas and sends the string to be processed by Coldfusion into a PNG file.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes I get a Coldfusion error:

"Verify your inputs. The Base64 data is not in proper format. Data should be in the format understood by the  tag in HTML, which is "data:image/jpg;base64,[base64 data]"

This happens only maybe 3% of the time. When I try to reproduce it using the exact same selections, it works fine.

This is the code that I'm using

```
<cfset image = imageReadBase64("#form.image#")>
<cfset fileName = #RandString(40)# & '.png'>

<cfimage 
    source="#image#" 
    destination="C:\something\#fileName#" 
    action="write"
    overwrite = "yes">
```

Thank you

Comment: The first thing that catches my eye is that you are saving to a png but coldfusion expects you to be saving to a jpg

Comment: I need it to be a png

Comment: Side note, if you cannot reproduce an issue on demand, add some error handling to trap the error. When it occurs, save the relevant values somewhere, so you can examine them later.

Comment: @RussellUhl - CFimage will convert it on-the-fly, based on the "destination" file extension. Jack - Though it seems like `imageReadBase64` is redundant. You could use the base64 string directly ie `<cfimage isBase64="true" source="#form.image#" ...>`

Comment: @Leigh It may convert it, but to me, that error means it's not even getting that far.  It can't read the source data properly, so there's nothing to convert in the first place.  I'm going to stand by my jpg/png discrepancy for the moment

Comment: (Edit) @RussellUhl - I was responding to your comment *"you are saving to a png but coldfusion expects you to be saving to a jpg"*.  The only place in the code that "saves" an image (or is concerned with jpg vs png) is the `<cfimage>`, so I assumed that is what you were referring to.  `ImageReadBase64` does not care about format, just that it receives a valid base64 string (with or without headers). However, agreed that the error occurs on the imageReadBase64 call, not cfimage.

Comment: I'm going to try remove imageReadBase64 and see if that resolves the issue

Comment: @JackPilowsky - I do not think that will help here.  ImageReadBase64 seems to be saying your input string is not valid base64. If that is the case, cfimage will probably throw the same error. I think you need to trap the error and save the string to find out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Ok, I have set a cftry/cfcatch thing to email me the string next time the problem shows up.